# How to add color border to image in [vba] [powerpoint]

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I need to add border to different images that I have in a power point presentation, I am also looking for how to send the image to the background behind the letters. Can someone help me

```
Sub ajustar2()

'imagenes  segunda diapo'

Set imagen1 = ActivePresentation.Slides(2)
imagen1.Shapes.AddPicture FileName:="D:\I\P\h.png", LinkToFile:=msoTrue, SaveWithDocument:=msoTrue, _
    Left:=10, Top:=75, Width:=433, Height:=330
    
Set imagen2 = ActivePresentation.Slides(2)
imagen2.Shapes.AddPicture FileName:="D:\I\P\d.png", LinkToFile:=msoTrue, SaveWithDocument:=msoTrue, _
    Left:=463, Top:=75, Width:=484, Height:=330

'imagenes  tercera diapo'

Set imagen1 = ActivePresentation.Slides(3)
imagen1.Shapes.AddPicture FileName:="D:\I\P\h.png", LinkToFile:=msoTrue, SaveWithDocument:=msoTrue, _
    Left:=10, Top:=75, Width:=433, Height:=330
    
Set imagen2 = ActivePresentation.Slides(3)
imagen2.Shapes.AddPicture FileName:="D:\I\P\v.png", LinkToFile:=msoTrue, SaveWithDocument:=msoTrue, _
    Left:=463, Top:=75, Width:=484, Height:=330
    
    ActivePresentation.Slides(2).Select
    Selection.ShapeRange.ZOrder msoSendToBack

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using Picture as Shape object and editing it's properties

```
Sub ajustar2()
Dim imagen1 As Slide, pic As Shape
Set imagen1 = ActivePresentation.Slides(1)
Set pic = imagen1.Shapes.AddPicture(FileName:="D:\INFORMES\PILAS\hazard.png", _
            LinkToFile:=msoTrue, SaveWithDocument:=msoTrue, Left:=10, Top:=75, _
            Width:=433, Height:=330)
With pic
.Line.Weight = 5
.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0) 'choose RGB color combination
.ZOrder (msoSendToBack)

End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Reference https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.shape.line

Comment: thanks, how can I add a color frame according to a number x

Comment: @Daxtrox Hi, please post another question on stack overflow. Currently, I am not accessing my PC and may need some time to answer this question. Also, please elaborate on "according to a number x" in that question.. posting from Android mobile.